# onActivityResult is not called (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult

I need help. On my `onCreate()` I have this code:

```
    takePhotoDialog = DialogGetPhotoFrom.getInstance().apply {
        setListener(object : DialogGetPhotoFrom.DialogListener {
            override fun onTakeFromGallery() {
                Log.v("ProjectDetails", "onTakeFromGallery called")
                val intent = Intent().apply {
                    type = "image/*"
                    action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
                }
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE)
            }

            override fun onTakePhoto() {
                dispatchTakePictureIntent()
            }
        })
    }

    projectDetails_pickImage.setOnClickListener { takePhotoDialog?.show(supportFragmentManager) }
```

An on my `onActivityResult`, I wrote:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE -> {
            Log.v("ProjectDetails", "REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE called")
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    try {
                        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(data.data)
                        val bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
                        projectDetails_image.setImageBitmap(bitMap)
                        // TODO Save image URI to database
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't set background.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.v("ProjectDetails", "data is null")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, `onActivityResult()` doesn't fire when an image is selected. What should I do?

Comment: Is that method `onActivyResult` inside of activity or fragment?

Comment: Inside an Activity. Anyway I already solved it. :) The solution is to put the codes inside onTakeFromGallery() to another function inside the Activity class and call that function insode the onTakeFromGallery(). I'll post my solution. hehe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it! The solution is to put the codes inside my onTakeGallery() function to a function that belongs to the Activity class. So my code will look like this:

```
takePhotoDialog = DialogGetPhotoFrom.getInstance().apply {
    setListener(object : DialogGetPhotoFrom.DialogListener {
        override fun onTakeFromGallery() {
            dispatchSelectFromGalleryIntent()
        }

        override fun onTakePhoto() {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent()
        }
    })
}

projectDetails_pickImage.setOnClickListener { 
    takePhotoDialog?.show(supportFragmentManager)
}
```

And the extracted codes goes here:

```
private fun dispatchSelectFromGalleryIntent() {
    val intent = Intent().apply {
        type = "image/*"
        action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    }
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Image"), REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE)
}
```